# Why is the document height equal to window inner height + pageYoffset?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to detect when an user has scroll to the very bottom of the page.

The solution that I end up with is the following

```
var windowHeight = "innerHeight" in window ? window.innerHeight : document.documentElement.offsetHeight;
var body = document.body, html = document.documentElement;
var docHeight = Math.max(body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight, html.clientHeight,  html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight);
var windowBottom = windowHeight + window.pageYOffset;

if (windowBottom >= docHeight) {
    // Bottom is reached
}
```

I am confused why this works

From the documentation, [innerheight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/innerHeight) is the height of the view portal, and [pageYoffset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollY) is the amount of scroll that we make.

So in order to detect scroll to bottom, shouldn't I check if `pageYOffset >= documentHeight` ?

Why do I have to add `innerheight`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Angular. This is how all browsers work.

Your `pageYOffset` is never going to be greater than the document height since it represents the top of the viewport. In order for `pageYOffset` to be equal to the document height, you'd have to scroll past the end of the page.

The maximum `pageYOffset` can be is the `docHeight - window.innerHeight`. So your check could be:

```
if (pageYOffset >= docHeight - window.innerHeight) {
    // Bottom is reached
}
```